Ruby on Rails - One form to create multiple objects and associations
I am trying to prepare an app where we can choose a flights and NUMBER OF PASSENGERS. Based on number of passengers(params[:_passengers] and chosen flight(params[:_chosen_flight_id]) I am preparing a view with form to gather Passengers data.

It's creating POST request to bookings#create action where I am trying to create 1 booking(flight_id,passenger_id) and associated passenger using booking.build_passenger method:
Started POST "/bookings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-12-18 17:18:29 +0100
Processing by BookingsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "_passengers"=>"2", "_chosen_flight_id"=>"7", "booking"=>{"0"=>{"passenger_attributes"=>{"passport_no"=>"123123123", "name"=>"Marek", "surname"=>"Surname"}}, "1"=>{"passenger_attributes"=>{"passport_no"=>"123123121", "name"=>"Marek", "surname"=>"Example"}}}, "button"=>""}
  Flight Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "flights".* FROM "flights" WHERE "flights"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb:14:in `create'
Unpermitted parameters: :0, :1. Context: { controller: BookingsController, action: create, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00007f49722664a8>, params: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "_passengers"=>"2", "_chosen_flight_id"=>"7", "booking"=>{"0"=>{"passenger_attributes"=>{"passport_no"=>"123123123", "name"=>"Marek", "surname"=>"Surname"}}, "1"=>{"passenger_attributes"=>{"passport_no"=>"123123121", "name"=>"Marek", "surname"=>"Example"}}}, "button"=>"",  "controller"=>"bookings", "action"=>"create"} }
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms (1 query, 0 cached) | GC: 0.0ms)



ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):

Code below:
#bookings_controller
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @bookings = []
    params[:_passengers].to_i.times do
      @bookings << Booking.new
    end
    @bookings.each do |booking|
      booking.build_passenger
    end
    @flight = Flight.find(params[:_chosen_flight_id])
  end

  def create
    @flight = Flight.find(params[:_chosen_flight_id])

    params[:_passengers].to_i.times do
      i = 0
      @booking = Booking.new
      @booking.flight = @flight
      @booking.build_passenger(params[:booking]["#{i}"][:passenger_attributes])
      i = i + 1
      puts "Booking no#{i}:"
      puts @booking.inspect
    end
  end

  private
  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:flight_id, passenger_attributes: [:passport_no, :name, :surname])
  end
end

#bookings/new.html.erb form
<%= form_tag bookings_path do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :_passengers, params[:_passengers] %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :_chosen_flight_id, params[:_chosen_flight_id] %>
  <ul>
  <% @bookings.each_with_index do |booking, i| %>
    Passenger information:
    <%= fields_for "booking[#{i}]", booking do |booking_form| %>
      <%= booking_form.fields_for :passenger do |passenger_form| %>
        <li>
        <%= passenger_form.label :passport_no %>
        <%= passenger_form.text_field :passport_no %>
        <%= passenger_form.label :name %>
        <%= passenger_form.text_field :name %>
        <%= passenger_form.label :surname %>
        <%= passenger_form.text_field :surname %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= button_tag "SUBMIT" %>
  </ul>
<% end %>

Any ideas how to iterate over my params and create booking-passenger pairs?

You are not using the booking_params method, you are just throwing unsafe params to create the new entries to the database, thats why it crashes. Also, are you using rails accepts_nested_attributes_for in the model ? I think it could work better.

I've added accepts_nested_attributes_for :passenger inside booking.rb file. There is also belongs_to :passenger line inside Booking class. Could you help me with building safe booking params as you mentioned? I am new to ruby on rails and I've already spent a lot of time trying to create those booking-passenger pairs.

Have a look at this plugin: https://www.stimulus-components.com/docs/stimulus-rails-nested-form.  Even if you don't use the plugin it gives you a good idea of how to use accepts_nested_attributes_for in the models and with strong params.

I would take a completely different approach where you have the user just create the booking itself and then have a separate route and controllers to add passengers to the recently created booking. It's going to be less complex and wonky and give a better user experience. That can be combined with Stimus to make it appear as one form to the user. You're falling victim to a pretty common trap here whenever someone tries to build any kind of checkout and they think that creating the record is the end of the road when it fact the sooner you do it the more resilient the process will be.

Quite simply, you need to use booking_params and not access the params object directly.
In the example below I changed passenger_attributes to passengers_attributes and the relationship to has_many passengers, then I changed the form to fields_for booking and fields_for :passengers, booking.passengers.build, you also need to accept_nested_attributes_for passengers.
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
    (params[:_passengers].to_i || 0).times { @booking.passengers.build }
    # @flight = Flight.find(params[:_chosen_flight_id])
  end

  def create
    # @flight = Flight.find(params[:_chosen_flight_id])
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
    if @booking.save
      redirect_to @booking
    else
      respond_with @booking
    end
  end

  private
  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:flight_id, passengers_attributes: [:passport_no, :name, :surname])
  end
end

class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :passengers
  has_one :flight
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :passengers
end

<%= hidden_field_tag :_passengers, params[:_passengers] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :_chosen_flight_id, params[:_chosen_flight_id] %>
<ul>
  <%= form_with model: @booking do |booking_form| %>
    <%= booking_form.fields_for :passengers do |passenger_form| %>
      Passenger information:
      <li>
        <%= passenger_form.label :passport_no %>
        <%= passenger_form.text_field :passport_no %>
        <%= passenger_form.label :name %>
        <%= passenger_form.text_field :name %>
        <%= passenger_form.label :surname %>
        <%= passenger_form.text_field :surname %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
    <%= booking_form.submit %>
  <% end %>
</ul>

tarted POST "/bookings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-12-19 21:27:08 -0500
Processing by BookingsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token" => "[FILTERED]", "booking" => {"passengers_attributes" => {"0" => {"passport_no" => "1", "name" => "2", "surname" => "3"}, "1" => {"passport_no" => "3", "name" => "4", "surname" => "5"}, "2" => {"passport_no" => "5", "name" => "4", "surname" => "4"}}}, "commit" => "Create Booking"}
  TRANSACTION (0.4ms)  BEGIN immediate TRANSACTION /*action='create',application='Bookings',controller='bookings'*/
  ↳ app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb:10:in 'BookingsController#create'
  Booking Create (2.1ms)  INSERT INTO "bookings" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ('2024-12-20 02:27:08.595012', '2024-12-20 02:27:08.595012') RETURNING "id" /*action='create',application='Bookings',controller='bookings'*/
  ↳ app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb:10:in 'BookingsController#create'
  Passenger Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "passengers" ("created_at", "updated_at", "booking_id", "passport_no", "name", "surname") VALUES ('2024-12-20 02:27:08.608990', '2024-12-20 02:27:08.608990', 18, '1', '2', '3') RETURNING "id" /*action='create',application='Bookings',controller='bookings'*/
  ↳ app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb:10:in 'BookingsController#create'
  Passenger Create (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "passengers" ("created_at", "updated_at", "booking_id", "passport_no", "name", "surname") VALUES ('2024-12-20 02:27:08.614035', '2024-12-20 02:27:08.614035', 18, '3', '4', '5') RETURNING "id" /*action='create',application='Bookings',controller='bookings'*/
  ↳ app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb:10:in 'BookingsController#create'
  Passenger Create (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "passengers" ("created_at", "updated_at", "booking_id", "passport_no", "name", "surname") VALUES ('2024-12-20 02:27:08.620005', '2024-12-20 02:27:08.620005', 18, '5', '4', '4') RETURNING "id" /*action='create',application='Bookings',controller='bookings'*/
  ↳ app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb:10:in 'BookingsController#create'
  TRANSACTION (13.3ms)  COMMIT TRANSACTION /*action='create',application='Bookings',controller='bookings'*/
  ↳ app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb:10:in 'BookingsController#create'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/bookings/18
Completed 302 Found in 75ms (ActiveRecord: 15.9ms (4 queries, 0 cached) | GC: 0.0ms)

❯ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 8.0.1)
bookings(dev)> Booking.last.passengers
  Booking Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "bookings".* FROM "bookings" ORDER BY "bookings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1 /*application='Bookings'*/
  Passenger Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "passengers".* FROM "passengers" WHERE "passengers"."booking_id" = 18 /* loading for pp */ LIMIT 11 /*application='Bookings'*/
=> 
[#<Passenger:0x00007d3f2b33ee50
  id: 7,
  created_at: "2024-12-20 02:27:08.608990000 +0000",
  updated_at: "2024-12-20 02:27:08.608990000 +0000",
  booking_id: 18,
  passport_no: "1",
  name: "2",
  surname: "3">,
 #<Passenger:0x00007d3f2b31bc20
  id: 8,
  created_at: "2024-12-20 02:27:08.614035000 +0000",
  updated_at: "2024-12-20 02:27:08.614035000 +0000",
  booking_id: 18,
  passport_no: "3",
  name: "4",
  surname: "5">,
 #<Passenger:0x00007d3f48c27bd0
  id: 9,
  created_at: "2024-12-20 02:27:08.620005000 +0000",
  updated_at: "2024-12-20 02:27:08.620005000 +0000",
  booking_id: 18,
  passport_no: "5",
  name: "4",
  surname: "4">]

Edits: Per comment, I changed to use form_with and build the passengers in the controller. You could refactor further but this fixes the bug.

Haven't seen your answer before - I've decided to change approach because I had really big problem with creating MULTIPLE Booking-Passenger pairs with belongs_to:has_one relation using ONE NESTED FORM. My solution is similar to your approach - changed relations Booking-Passenger to has_many:belongs_to & I am using nested form - "form_with model: @booking do |bf|" + "bf.fields_for :passengers do |pf|".

I've probably found one problem with your solution - it'll create Booking with data provided for LAST passenger, right? Looking at your params u've selected to book a flight for 3 passengers but your passenger_attributes hash has only one passenger record. If I understand correctly you will fill up form for 3 passengers and end up with creating only one passenger record (for last passenger data provided). Am I right? I haven't tested it yet, I will be able to check this solution tomorrow by running the code. I'll later also post my code for others with solution that's currently working for me.

@mareks that's true, this doesn't work completely and would require some tweaking to work within the intention of your application and more changes would be needed. This was to get you past the error you were getting. you can tweak it further. I wasn't sure if you wanted a 1:1 Booking or to have 1 Booking with many Passengers which is what I changed it to.

@mareks I made some edits to fix the bug. You should see 3 passengers getting created now. Please try.

That's basically the correct solution in my opinion. It is much less complex approach than creating (booking-passenger belongs_to:has_one) pairs as I used to do before. In your fixed answer we're creating one Booking(Parent) with multiple Passengers(children) records - that fits to approach recommended in rails docs for nested forms. But I think I would leave belongs_to :flight in Booking model (in my opinion booking should store flight_id).  Thank you for your time Andrew!

You're welcome, @mareks. Nothing wrong with leaving the flight id, I just didn't generate that model for my example.

I've marked Andrew's answer as accepted because it fixes problem from the question. I've refactored my models and code a bit more and I'll post it here - maybe someone will use similar approach in the future.
#models/Booking.rb
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize :set_defaults

  belongs_to :flight
  has_many :passengers, inverse_of: :booking, dependent: :destroy #IMPORTANT CHANGE

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :passengers

  validates :flight_id, :booking_value, presence: true
  validates :payment_verified, inclusion: { in: [ true, false ] }

  private
  def set_defaults
    self.payment_verified = false
  end
end

#models/Passenger.rb
class Passenger < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :booking, inverse_of: :passengers #IMPORTANT CHANGE

  validates :name, :surname, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 30 }
  validates :email, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }, presence: true
end

#views/bookings/new.html.erb
<h1>NEW FORM</h1>
<%= render "flights/flight_details", flight: @flight %>
<%= render "booking_passengers_form", booking: @booking %>


#views/bookings/_booking_passengers_form.html.erb
<%= form_with model: booking do |booking_form| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :_chosen_flight_id, params[:_chosen_flight_id] %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :_passengers, params[:_passengers] %>
  <%= booking_form.hidden_field :flight_id, value: params[:_chosen_flight_id] %>
  <ul>
    <strong>Passenger information:</strong>
    <%= booking_form.fields_for :passengers do |passenger_form| %>
    <li>
      <%= passenger_form.label :name %>
      <%= passenger_form.text_field :name %>
      <%= passenger_form.label :surname %>
      <%= passenger_form.text_field :surname %>
      <%= passenger_form.label :email %>
      <%= passenger_form.email_field :email %>
    </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <%= booking_form.submit "SUBMIT" %>
<% end %>

class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @flight = Flight.find(params[:_chosen_flight_id])
    @booking = Booking.new
    params[:_passengers].to_i.times do
      @booking.passengers.build
    end
  end
  def create
    @flight = Flight.find(params[:_chosen_flight_id])
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
    @booking.booking_value = @flight.price * params[:_passengers].to_i
    if @booking.save
      redirect_to @booking
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def show
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:flight_id, passengers_attributes: [:booking_id, :name, :surname, :email])
  end
end

DESCRIPTION OF CHANGES:

changed some columns in Booking & Passenger models/migrations (not important at all).
IMPORTANT CHANGE: Changed relation from Flight::has_many::Bookings(belongs_to Flight) & Passenger::has_many::Bookings(belongs_to Passenger) TO Flight::has_many::Bookings(belongs_to Flight) & Booking::has_many::Passengers(belongs_to Booking). This way we are working with nested forms as described in Rails Docs - using parent object(Booking) we're creating multiple childrens(Passengers).

